# org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Couldn't find MIME boundary

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, jax-ws, mime

Trying to Troubleshoot an issue which complains about missing MIME boundary.

I'm calling a soap webservice, looks like the the exception coming from parsing the response? dose anyone know about any possible cause?

```
2016-07-25 18:39:51.373 +0000 [lcbatch-scheduler_Worker-1] [WARN] o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain   - Interceptor for {http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/model/erpIntegrationService/}ErpIntegrationServiceService#{http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/financials/commonModules/shared/model/erpIntegrationService/}uploadFileToUcm has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Couldn't find MIME boundary: ------=_Part_679_384721743.1469471991267
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AttachmentInInterceptor.handleMessage(AttachmentInInterceptor.java:60)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:798)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1641)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1532)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1330)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:652)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:514)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:423)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:324)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:277)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:139)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy156.uploadFileToUcm(Unknown Source)
```

apache cxf dependencies i'm using:

```
+- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-wsdl:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-policy:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:3.1.2:compile
```

Answer (score 2):

You are receiving a Multipart message (as described on https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html).

You could start by verifying the value of the header "Content-Type". It should be something like

```
Content-Type : multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; boundary="----=_Part_679_384721743.1469471991267"
```

Then, you could examine the content of the response, that may give you an idea of what is missing.
In order to examine the content, you could use Wiremock as a proxy to intercept everything that goes over the wire (http://wiremock.org/docs/proxying/). For instance, I recently did that and Wiremock recorded this for me

```
--uuid:0a6c8ffe-9f63-4fdb-a416-43acd1044b8b
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <root.message@cxf.apache.org>

<soap:Envelope   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body> <myxml>....</myxml></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
--uuid:0a6c8ffe-9f63-4fdb-a416-43acd1044b8b--
```

In my case, **uuid:0a6c8ffe-9f63-4fdb-a416-43acd1044b8b** is the MIME boundary.